# Readsession bigquery from powerbi

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, google-bigquery-storage-api

If a refresh of a dataset powerbi from bigquery is in progress, and meanwhile I have an update of the view bigquery used in the refresh , it can be problematic?
PowerBi can continue the refresh of the dataset from the stream of readsession ? or all streams will be removed because the view is updated ? (the update is create or replace the view)